# How to just print a simple traceback of the exception passed to the errorhandler function in python flask

Tags: python, flask

I have some code written in python flask, where I have a function as follows:

```
@app.errorhandler(500)
def internal_error(exception):
    print "500 error caught"
```

But this message is not sufficient enough to provide me with enough information. I just want to print the traceback for the exception that is passed to errorhandler. Is there any way to do this simple thing?

Comment: If you are running flask behind a proxy like gunicorn or uwsgi, you will not be able to use the flask debugger. A much better solution is to run the flask standalone server with `debug=True` enabled to see the full debugger. You would then access it (by default) at http://www.example.com:5000

Answer (score 9):

Assuming that the error handler is called from within a context when the exception and traceback are still available from `sys`, you should be able to use [`traceback.format_exc`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/traceback.html#traceback.format_exc).

```
import traceback

@app.errorhandler(500)
def internal_error(exception):
    print "500 error caught"
    print traceback.format_exc()
```

Comment: So, I won't need to use the passed argument `exception` in printing the traceback? Just `traceback.format_exc()` will suffice?

Comment: It _should_.  I don't know the details of Flask's exception handling, but usually, the exception (and traceback, etc) are available from [`sys.exc_info()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/sys.html#sys.exc_info), so `traceback` doesn't need a reference to the exception or the traceback.

Answer (score 1):

I think you can solve it like this:

```
import sys
import traceback

@app.errorhandler(500)
def internal_error(exception):
    print("500 error caught")
    etype, value, tb = sys.exc_info()
    print(traceback.print_exception(etype, value, tb))
```

You can print the traceback information

Comment: Missing parentheses

Comment: For your example to work as intended you should use format_exception(). The print_exception() prints the exception and returns None. The print() function call does not actually print anything.