# How can I write a route to receive Content Security Policy report with Flask without getting a 400 Bad Request error (flask_wtf.csrf.CSRFError)?

Tags: python, security, flask, content-security-policy, bad-request

##### TL;DR: Apologies for the long post. In a nutshell I am trying to debug a CSP `report-uri`. If I am missing critical information please let me know.

CSP implementation: [Flask-Talisman](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/flask-talisman)
The attribute that needs to be set: `content_security_policy_report_uri`

There does not seem to be a lot of information out there on how to capture this report
I can't find anything specific in the `Flask-Talisman` documentation

As `Flask-Talisman` only sets headers, including the `report-uri`, I imagine this is outside the scope of the extension anyway

#### The route

All resources I've found have roughly the same function:
https://www.merixstudio.com/blog/content-security-policy-flask-and-django-part-2/
http://csplite.com/csp260/
https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/flask-talisman/issues/21

The only really detailed explanation I've found for this route is below (it is not related to `Flask-Talisman` however)

From https://www.merixstudio.com/blog/content-security-policy-flask-and-django-part-2/ (This is what I am currently using)

```py
# app/routes/report.py

import json
import pprint
    
from flask import request, make_response, Blueprint
...
bp = Blueprint("report", __name__, url_prefix="report")
...
@bp.route('/csp-violations', methods=['POST'])
def report():
    """Receive a post request containing csp-resport.
    This is the report-uri. Print report to console and 
    return Response object.

    :return: Flask Response object.
    """
    pprint.pprint(json.loads(str(request.data, 'utf-8')))
    response = make_response()
    response.status_code = 200
    return response
    ...
```

This route only receives a 400 error and I am at a loss in finding out how to actually debug this

```
127.0.0.1 - - [04/Nov/2021 14:29:09] "POST /report/csp-violations HTTP/1.1" 400 -
```

I have tried with a GET request and could see I am receiving an empty request, which seems to mean that the CSP report isn't being delivered (response from `https://127.0.0.1:5000/report/csp-violations`)

```py
# app/routes/report.py
...
@bp.route('/csp-violations', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def report():
    ...
```

```
b''
b''
127.0.0.1 - - [04/Nov/2021 18:03:52] "GET /report/csp_violations HTTP/1.1" 200 -
```

Edit: Definitely receiving nothing

```py
...
@bp.route("/csp_violations", methods=["GET", "POST"])
def report():
    ...
    return str(request.args)  # ImmutableMultiDict([ ])
```

Will not work with a GET or POST request (still 400)

```py
...
@bp.route("/csp_violations", methods=["GET", "POST"])
def report():
    content = request.get_json(force=True)
    ...
```

Without `force=True`

```py
@bp.route("/csp_violations", methods=["GET", "POST"])
def report():
    content = request.get_json()  # json.decoder.JSONDecodeError
    ...
```

#### Chromium (same result on Chrome, Brave, and FireFox)

When I check this out on Chromium under CTRL-SHIFT-I > Network I see

```
Request URL: https://127.0.0.1:5000/report/csp_violations
Request Method: POST
Status Code: 400 BAD REQUEST
Remote Address: 127.0.0.1:5000
Referrer Policy: strict-origin-when-cross-origin
```

But apparently the payload does exist at the bottom under "Request Payload"...

```json
{
    "document-uri": "https://127.0.0.1:5000/",
    "referrer": "",
    "violated-directive": "script-src-elem",
    "effective-directive": "script-src-elem",
    "original-policy": "default-src 'self' https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com https://cdn.cloudflare.com https://cdn.jsdelivr.net https://gravatar.com jquery.js; report-uri /report/csp-violations",
    "disposition": "enforce",
    "blocked-uri": "inline",
    "line-number": 319,
    "source-file": "https://127.0.0.1:5000/",
    "status-code": 200,
    "script-sample": ""
}
```

#### Is the CSP blocking this request?

After reading [Python Flask 400 Bad Request Error Every Request](https://stackoverflow.com/q/65975905/13316671) I set all requests to HTTPS with the help of https://stackoverflow.com/a/63708394/13316671
This fixed a few unittests but no change to the 400 error for this particular route

```py
# app/config.py
from environs import Env
from flask import Flask

env = Env()
    
env.read_env()
 
    
class Config:
    """Load environment."""
    ...

    @property
    def PREFERRED_URL_SCHEME(self) -> str:  # noqa
        return env.str("PREFERRED_URL_SCHEME", default="https")
        ...
    
# app/__init__.py
from app.config import Config


def create_app() -> Flask:
    app = Flask(__name__)
    app.config.from_object(Config())
    ...
    return app
```

```sh
flask run --cert="$HOME/.openssl/cert.pem" --key="$HOME/.openssl/key.pem"
```

#### 400 Bad Request

Through what I've read a 400 Bad Request error usually happens from an empty request or form

https://stackoverflow.com/a/14113958/13316671

```
...the issue is that Flask raises an HTTP error when it fails to find a key in 
the args and form dictionaries. What Flask assumes by default is that if you 
are asking for a particular key and it's not there then something got 
left out of the request and the entire request is invalid.
```

https://stackoverflow.com/a/37017020/13316671

```
99% of the time, this error is a key error caused by your requesting a key in 
the request.form dictionary that does not exist. To debug it, run

print(request.form)
```

`request.data` in my case

Through trying to fix this I have gone down the rabbit-hole in regard to just seeing the cause of the 400 error

I have implemented the following

https://stackoverflow.com/a/34172382/13316671

```py
import traceback
    
from flask import Flask  
...
app = Flask(__name__)
    ...
    @app.errorhandler(400)
    def internal_error(exception):  # noqa
        print("400 error caught")
        print(traceback.format_exc())
```

And added the following to my config
I haven't checked, but I think these values already get set alongside `DEBUG`

```py
# app/config.py
from environs import Env
    
env = Env()
    
env.read_env()
    
    
class Config:
    """Load environment."""
    ...
 
    @property
    def TRAP_HTTP_EXCEPTIONS(self) -> bool:  # noqa
        """Report traceback on error."""
        return env.bool("TRAP_HTTP_EXCEPTIONS", default=self.DEBUG)  # noqa
    
    @property
    def TRAP_BAD_REQUEST_ERRORS(self) -> bool:  # noqa
        """Report 400 traceback on error."""
        return env.bool("TRAP_BAD_REQUEST_ERRORS", default=self.DEBUG)  # noqa   
    ...
```

I still am not getting a traceback. The only time werkzeug shows a traceback is through a complete crash, for something like a syntax error

It seems, because I am not initializing this request that the app continues to run through the 400 code, no problem

#### Summary

Main conclusion I'm drawing is that for some reason the `report-uri` is not valid because I can see the payload exists, I am just not receiving it

I used the relative route as the subdomain would be different for a localhost and a remote. It looks as though the request is being made to the full URL in the Chromium snippet though.

Could I be receiving invalid headers https://stackoverflow.com/a/45682197? If so how can I debug that?

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Content-Security-Policy/report-uri
Note: The `report-uri` is deprecated, but I don't think most browsers support the `report-to` parameter

#### EDIT:

I have taken the following out of my application factory
(this code renders my exceptions - which I posted as an answer here so it is available https://stackoverflow.com/a/69671506/13316671

```py
...
    app = Flask(__name__)
    config.init_app(app)
    ...
    # exceptions.init_app(app)
    ...
    return app
```

After doing this (on FireFox Private mode), I made another POST (I've removed the GET method)
I can see the response - here I have managed to collect a Werkzeug traceback finally:

```
wtforms.validators.ValidationError: The CSRF token is missing.
```

Working out how to authenticate a csp-report coming from the browser

So far I've had a look at this: [Add a new Http Header in Content-Security-Policy-Report-Only "report-uri" POST call](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63557030)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For now I have exempted the view from `CRSFProtect`.
I think that should be fine as this view does not return a template, so I haven't been able to add

```html
<form method="post">
    {{ form.csrf_token }}
</form>
```

And the below didn't work for me (Don't think it's a valid token)

```py
# app/routes/report.py
...
def report():
    response = make_response()
    response.headers["X-CSRFToken"] = csrf.generate_csrf()
    ...
    return response
...
```

With the instantiated `CSRFProtect` object...

```py
# app/extensions.py
...
from flask_wtf.csrf import CSRFProtect
...
csrf_protect = CSRFProtect()
...
def init_app(app: Flask) -> None:
    ...
    csrf_protect.init_app(app)
    ...
...
```

...decorate the view

```py
# app/routes/report.py
from app.extensions import csrf_protect
...
@blueprint.route("/csp_violations", methods=["POST"])
@csrf_protect.exempt
def report():
    ....
```

```
127.0.0.1 - - [06/Nov/2021 21:30:46] "POST /report/csp_violations HTTP/1.1" 204 -
{
    "csp-report": {
        "blocked-uri": "inline",
        "column-number": 8118,
        "document-uri": "https://127.0.0.1:5000/",
        "line-number": 3,
        "original-policy": "default-src" ...
        "referrer": "",
        "source-file": ...
    }
}
```

I had a system going where my errors were obfuscated, so that's my mistake. This is not the first time I've had trouble with `CSRFProtect`.

I've fixed the debugging problem with

```py
# app/exceptions.py
...
def init_app(app: Flask) -> None:
    ...
    def render_error(error: HTTPException) -> Tuple[str, int]:

        # the below code is new
        app.logger.error(error.description)
       ...
...
```

So, this is what I would see now if I was still getting this error

```
[2021-11-06 21:23:56,054] ERROR in exceptions: The CSRF token is missing.
127.0.0.1 - - [06/Nov/2021 21:23:56] "POST /report/csp_violations HTTP/1.1" 400 -
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this piece of code:

```
@app.route('/report-csp-violations', methods=['POST'])
    def report():
        content = request.get_json(force=True)   # that's where the shoe pinches
        print(json.dumps(content, indent=4, sort_keys=True))
        response = make_response()
        response.status_code = 204
        return response
```

I think that `request.data` tries automatically parse JSON data and for success parsing it expects `application/json` MIME type been sent.
But violation reports is sent with the `application/csp-report` MIME type, therefore Flask considers it as a wrong data  from the client -> 404 Bad Request.

`.get_json(force=True)` means ignore the mimetype and always try to parse JSON.

Also I don't think you need to do a conversion to utf-8 because  according to [rfc4627](https://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc4627.txt) "3.  Encoding":

*JSON text SHALL be encoded in Unicode. The default encoding is UTF-8.*

Comment: Ty, this gave me a little more insight - appreciated. It seems that it has pinpointed the reason for my 400 error (perhaps) - I tried it with the POST request only, same result, but with the GET request it also continued to throw a 400 error - meaning I am getting nothing back from the browser. However this doesn't happen on the get with request.data, and when I don't put in force=True I get a key error. Wondering why I am not receiving this report.

Comment: I have made an error, use  `print(json.dumps(content, indent=4, sort_keys=True))` to print JSON, not `pprint.pprint(json.loads(str(content, 'utf-8')))`. You already have a parsed JSON in the `content` variable.

Comment: Ty again for your help, this didn't work unfortunately, but now I know why. I managed to collect the traceback after some configuring, I've added it to the end of my question. Wondering if you would know "...how to authenticate (CSRF token) a csp-report coming from the browser"? I have a look at this but didn't get round to a deep dive yet https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63557030